# How to change tabs on a TabLayout when scrolling through a ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I added a `TabLayout` to my layout XML, and instead of the classic `ViewPager`, I just have one `NestedScrollView`. My problem is when I try to change tabs depending on the position of the page (e.g., `OnScrollChangeListener`), I use `tabLayout.getTabAt(3).select();`, but it screws up the tabs before it.

Any tabs before the 4th tab (`getTabAt(3)` == 4th tab) become unselectable. When I click it, it just selects the 4th tab.

Comment: I assumed you meant `OnScrollChangeListener` instead of `ScrollViewListener`. Please correct that if I'm wrong.

Comment: your right. THanks

Comment: This answer may help you. [Tab change on scroll.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77717069/2289835)