# Change tab based on recycler view header while scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, tabview

[image]

I'm trying to change the tab as we scroll through the recycler view.

I have listed the items in single recycler view.

So when i reach the header ( f*or example Breakfast then Breakfast tab should be active* ) of each section how to change tab accordingly?

The above gif explains my query. Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: You will have to get visible record from recyclerview onScroll and then check the record item until you reach Breakfast record and then change the tab to Breakfast thats it.. Have a look for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/34586637/6945674

Comment: Instead of using multiple fragments, you have to use segmented recycler view and then change tab on `onScroll` according to visible recycler view section.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem

Comment: hi bro did you find any solution ?

Comment: No bro, I don't do app development anymore :D. I think by now there will be other solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved either way by using RecyclerView or NestedScrollView.

We can set horizontal RecyclerView instead of Tabs.

You need to observe the scroll and change the position of the horizontal RecyclerView.
On the other hand, by clicking on the horizontal RecyclerView, You can change the position of the content and scroll to the desired view.

```
val scrollBounds = Rect()
binding.sv.getHitRect(scrollBounds)

binding.sv.setOnScrollChangeListener(NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
    if (binding.testDataView0.tvContentTitle1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
        if (!binding.testDataView0.tvContentTitle1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)
            || scrollBounds.height() < binding.testDataView0.tvContentTitle1.height
        ) {
            Log.e(TAG, "tvContentTitle1 displayed partial portion")
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "tvContentTitle1 displayed full portion")
        }
        selectedTitlePosition = 0
        setTitleSelected()

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "tvContentTitle1 Not displayed")
    }
})
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can have a look at [This GitHub project (Tab change on scroll)](https://github.com/RumitPatel/android-tab-change-on-scroll) for implementation.