# Changes the tab position when moving the scroll view instead of clicking the tab in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to use the tab layout without using the view pager.

In the scroll view, I need to change the tab position when the scroll Y position value passes a specific layout.

I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Please check my code below

```
 mainScrollview.viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener {
            val scrollY: Int = mainScrollview.scrollY
            var currentTabLayout: TabLayout = tabs

                if (scrollY > (lay_product_vintage.height)) {
                            currentTabLayout.selectedTabPosition == 1
                        }  else if (scrollY > (lay_product_review.height)) {
                            currentTabLayout.selectedTabPosition == 2
                        }
            
        }
```

Comment: This answer may help you. [Tab change on scroll.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77717069/2289835)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectedTabPosition` does not have a setter, you're also using equals operator (`==`) while you actually meant to use assignment (`=`).

Selecting tabs using their position is done through the tab itself in `TabLayout`:

```
currentTabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();   // selects second tab
```